# Unable to export VSTS template using Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the following API however I am unable to extract the template.

https://my.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processadmin/processes/export/a3939163-8d2c-4027-b4cd-8c5b5385ef16?api-version=4.1-preview

I am getting the following error, I have checked the Process Id and it is correct

{
    "count": 1,
    "value": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred."
    }
}

The header info is as follows:
ActivityId →58919c6e-80c8-4e23-8615-b1420c8b33d1
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →56
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 15 Mar 2018 23:18:37 GMT
Expires →-1
P3P →CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Pragma →no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS →SAMEORIGIN
X-MSEdge-Ref →Ref A: 55BDC5BAB8FB4AA9B6F57D7E425CB98F Ref B: SYD03EDGE0409 Ref C: 2018-03-15T23:18:38Z
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-TFS-ProcessId →f4e9e458-9463-41a1-aee4-55eaaf18e13e
X-TFS-Session →58919c6e-80c8-4e23-8615-b1420c8b33d1
X-VSS-E2EID →58919c6e-80c8-4e23-8615-b1420c8b33d1
X-VSS-UserData →609b16af-5515-6e7c-996d-ed1e05e49cf1:bajwa79@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue, and have submitted a feedback at website below, let's wait for the response:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/216545/unable-to-export-vsts-template-using-rest-api.html

---

Update:

This feedback has been answered:

> In phase 2 or Inherited process model, process XML concept doesn't
>   exist. It is only for OnPrem XML model (in TFS) and for Hosted XML
>   process models. The process for which you are making this Rest API
>   call is an inherited process that's why it's failing. And you don't
>   need process XML to perform any operation you have different and easy
>   ways to do so in VSTS. Hope it answers your question. Let me know if
>   you have any other question.

Comment: So basically for pure VSTS projects, you can't customize the templates or items anymore beyond what is available in the web interface?